# why do I get an error when i try remove public dir from laravel with htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

i want to remove `public` from the generated URL in laravel by `htacces` . so

i have created `.htacces` file in the laravel root directory with this content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

but when I go to the `localhost/myapp`. i get this error

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Note That : i'm using laravel 5

how can i fix this . thanks

Comment: What's `line 161` of the `RouteCollection.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create `.htaccess` file, just point web server to a `public` directory, instead of root one.

Settings for Apache's `httpd.conf`:

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/myapp/public"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/myapp/public">
```

Don't forget to reload Apache after you made these changes.

Comment: i have another projetc in `wamp/www` . actually the root of my laravel's projetc is `wamp/www/myapp`

Comment: i want to edit 2 or more project at same times . and if I set This setting every time that i want to edit another projetct I have to change setting for that project and it's a little vain

Comment: The right way to use multiple projects is to create multiple hosts. Use this tutorial (or similar, there is a bunch of them) to setup WAMP: https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/creating-multiple-virtual-websites-in-wampserver/